# How to vectorize a loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, cell, vectorization

I want to use a function repmat to write this code:

```
   for j=1:30
       for i=1:10 
          myObject{i,j}.s = zeros(6,1);
       end
   end
```

I cannot understand how to do that for cells. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `deal`:

```
[myObject{1:10,1:30}] = deal( struct('s',zeros(6,1) );
```

PS: It is best [not to use `i` and `j` as variables in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Comment: Why encourage duplicate questions? =/